# UITableView Checkbox ( Select a button when another button is pressed )

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, checkbox, uibutton

I have a button called **btnChk2** . I want when the user press the **btnChk2** that the button **btnChk** get selected. Here is my code what happens in my code is that when **btnChk2** is pressed **btnChk2** get selected and not **btnChk**.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckBoxCell")

    if let lbl = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
        lbl.text = "item-\(1)"
    }

    if let btnChk = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton {
        btnChk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    if let btnChk2 = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
        btnChk2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    return cell!
}

@objc func checkboxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Handel Work Better than this ,you have to Do this logic in your `cell` and `CellforRow` only manage state

Any way you can do it like that

```
 @objc func checkboxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell else {
            return
        }

        if  sender.tag == 2 {

            if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
                if btnChk2.isSelected == true {
                    btnChk2.isSelected = false

                }else{
                    btnChk2.isSelected = true

                }
            }
            sender.isSelected = false
        }else if sender.tag == 100{
            if let btnChk = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton {
                if btnChk.isSelected == true {
                    btnChk.isSelected = false

                }else{
                    btnChk.isSelected = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried your code but when I press the btnChk2 the btnChk2 get selected, but me I want when I press the btnChk2 to get the btnChk selected.

Comment: worked just changed but when I repress the button does not get deselected

Comment: you need What, when press 2 one selected and when press 1 if selected to be deselcted

Comment: When I added `btnChk2.isSelected = !btnChk2.isSelected` the button stopped getting selected. here is the code `if  sender.tag == 2 {
            if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
                btnChk2.isSelected = true
                btnChk2.isSelected = !btnChk2.isSelected
            }
        }else if sender.tag == 100{
            if let btnChk = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton {
                btnChk.isSelected = true
                btnChk.isSelected = !btnChk.isSelected
            }
        }`

Comment: you need What, when press 2 one selected and when press 1 if selected to be deselcted – Abdelahad Darwish 4 mins ago    edit

Comment: I want when I press btnChk2 to get btnChk selected (this worked in your code up ) I also want when I repress btnChk2 to get btnChk deselected.

Comment: Worked!, Thank you.

Comment: can you please update the code that when I quit the app and come back the status of the checkbox is the same for exemple if a row checkbox is selected, I want when the user leaves the app and comeback the same checkbox stay selected, tried it with NSUserDefaults but didn't worked with me.

Comment: okay thank you, because I tried it with NSUserDefaults but can't seem to make it work, do you want me to show you my code?

Comment: yes update it , I'm out until now when i back i will do it

Comment: Created a new question, if you can answer it there please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655510/save-the-select-state-of-a-button-in-table-view-row-swift