# Save the select state of a button in UITableView row (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, row, nsuserdefaults

I have a button called `btnChk2` on a `UITableview` row. When the user press the `btnChk2` that the button `btnChk` get selected. The code above works to make that happen but when I quit the app and open it back up the status of the checkbox is the not the same, what I want for example is that if a row checkbox is selected, I want when the user leaves the app and comeback the same checkbox stay selected, tried it with `NSUserDefaults` but didn't worked with me.

Here is the code that works but it doesn't save the state of the checkbox:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckBoxCell")
    if let lbl = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
        lbl.text = "item-\(1)"
    }

    if let btnChk = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton {
        btnChk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    if let btnChk2 = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
        btnChk2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    return cell!
}

@objc func checkboxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell else {
        return
    }

    if  sender.tag == 2 {

        if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
            if btnChk2.isSelected == true {
                btnChk2.isSelected = false
            }else{
                btnChk2.isSelected = true
            }
        }
        sender.isSelected = false
    }else if sender.tag == 100{
        if let btnChk = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton {
            if btnChk.isSelected == true {
                btnChk.isSelected = false

            }else{
                btnChk.isSelected = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is NSUserdefault part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good suggestion don't use userdefault for this purpose, user default only use for user setting purpose, It's best to use core data or save in plist file. anyway here is solution using `UserDefaults`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell!
    // code to check for a particular tableView to display the data .
    if tableView == ScheduleTableView{



        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ScheduleCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        let lblCity = cell.viewWithTag(1)as! UILabel
        lblCity.text = ScheduleArray[indexPath.row] as String

        if let btnChk2 = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
            btnChk2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(22) as? UIButton {

            btnChk2.isSelected = (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: String(format: "indexpath%d", (indexPath.row))) == indexPath.row) ? true : false
        }  
    }
    if tableView == GoalsTableView{
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalsCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        let lbl3 = cell.viewWithTag(2)as! UILabel
        lbl3.text = GoalsArray[indexPath.row]as? String
    }
    return cell
}


@objc func checkboxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("AAAA")

    // sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


    guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell else {
        return
    }

    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.ScheduleTableView)
    let indexPath = self.ScheduleTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

    if  sender.tag == 100 {

        if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(22) as? UIButton {
            if btnChk2.isSelected == true {
                btnChk2.isSelected = false
                UserDefaults.standard.set(-1, forKey: String(format: "indexpath%d", (indexPath?.row)!))

            }else{
                btnChk2.isSelected = true
                UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath?.row, forKey: String(format: "indexpath%d", (indexPath?.row)!))
            }
        }
        sender.isSelected = false
    }


}
```

Comment: Didint work for me, what happens in your code is that for exemple if I select the button of a tableview row and then quit and reopen the app, all the buttons of the tableview rows are selected

Comment: if you can do it with core data, no problem

Comment: best option is coredata or save more than two value save in plist file against row at index path

Comment: Can you update the code with the steps so I can try it.

Comment: save indexpath also in userdefault, and when you load it just check userdefault indexpath is equel to current one then add check box selected

Comment: didn't work with me, can you please update your code.

Comment: it should work , otherwise pass me your code i can test with it, mshauket.developer@gmail.com

Comment: The error I get is `Attempt to insert non-property list object <NSIndexPath: 0x1cc036cc0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} for key indexpath`I sent the project to your email, thanks for your help!

Comment: hey, just wondering if you can answer my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834323/checkbox-in-uitableview-is-reselected-when-deleted-swift/50834421#50834421

Comment: yes, please if you can send me the updated project by email, thanks!

Comment: I think it is something to do with `if editingStyle == .delete {` where I remove the row but maybe I should also deselect the checkbox of the row

Answer (score 0):

You can save the selected button number in NSUserDefault and then use the same in your cellForRowAtIndexpath.
like as

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"button1";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"SelectedButton"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"SelectedButton"];
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexpath you can check with the values from  NSUserDefaults

Comment: I am using swift, can you update the code with swift, and the code for cellForRowAtIndexpath