# Checkbox in UITableView not working when row is deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row, nsuserdefaults

I have implemented a checkbox in UITableView controller, it works perfectly but when the checkbox are selected and the rows in the tableview are deleted and the when I add a new row to the tableview it gets selected.
Here is a link  to my project: https://files.fm/f/tepkz2du
I think it has something to do with when a row is delete, the index path is messed up.

**UPDATED CODE:**

**cellForRowAt:**

```
if let btnChk3 = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
            btnChk3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(22) as? UIButton {
        btnChk2.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: myarray[indexPath.row]) == (indexPath.row + index) ? true : false
    }
```

**checkboxClicked**

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduleArray") ?? [String]()
    if  sender.tag == 100 {

        if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(22) as? UIButton {
            if btnChk2.isSelected == true {
                btnChk2.isSelected = false
                UserDefaults.standard.set(-1, forKey: myarray[(indexPath?.row)!] )
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            }else{
                btnChk2.isSelected = true
                UserDefaults.standard.set((indexPath?.row)! + index, forKey: myarray[(indexPath?.row)!])
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
        }
        sender.isSelected = false
    }
```

**editingStyle == .delete:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

    if tableView == ScheduleTableView{


        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduleArray") ?? [String]()
        print(myarray)
        myarray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        defaults.set(myarray, forKey: "ScheduleArray")
        ScheduleTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't save index path in UserDefaults , save any value which you are showing in table cell. And match it with array in cellForRowAtIndex . like I did

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! tabCell
    c.lblC.text = arry?[indexPath.row]
    /* for example
     arry = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth","Seventh","eight","Ninth","Tenth"]
    seleted = ["First","Fifth"]
    */
    print("indexpath--",indexPath.row)
    if selected != nil
    {
        if (selected?.contains((arry?[indexPath.row])!))!
        {
            c.btnCheck.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "check.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            c.btnCheck.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        }


    }
    c.btnCheck.tag = indexPath.row
    c.btnCheck.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnCheckClick(btn:)) , for: .touchUpInside)
    return c
}
```

I am not able to run your code ...
thats way I made my demo
check it, hope you can get an idea...
https://files.fm/u/hj7jz9dj

Comment: Hey, thanks for the project just one thing if you can implement in it a way to save the rows that are selected, so when the user leaves and come back the rows that are selected stays the same, and the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {` Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can save selected array in UserDefault . And access it on this view.

Comment: If you find  answer helpful so please up vote it or accept it.

Comment: let me know if You facing any problem in using UserDefault

Comment: Do you mind updating your project with `UserDefault` and `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {` because these are what is not working with me.

Comment: I tried your code with my project, but it didn't work https://files.fm/u/uc6h6gdx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173206/discussion-between-deepti-raghav-and-coderj13).

Comment: I am implemented your code and it works, I just still need moveRowAt. If you could please update your answer with it so I can mark your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

```
if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(22) as? UIButton {
            btnChk2.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: myarray[indexPath.row]) == (indexPath.row + index) ? true : false
        }
```

CHANGE IN `cellForRowAt`

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduleArray") ?? [String]()
if  sender.tag == 100 {

            if let btnChk2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(22) as? UIButton {
                if btnChk2.isSelected == true {
                    btnChk2.isSelected = false
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(-1, forKey: myarray[(indexPath?.row)!] )
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                }else{
                    btnChk2.isSelected = true
                    UserDefaults.standard.set((indexPath?.row)! + index, forKey: myarray[(indexPath?.row)!])
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                }
            }
            sender.isSelected = false
        }
```

CHANGE IN checkboxClicked

Comment: yes it solve the problem, but if a row is selected and the app is closed and opened the row state is not saved therefore the row is not selected.

Comment: just min i'll ping you.

Comment: my email is JakeElMir@gmail.com if you would like to send me the updated project there.

Comment: CHECK OUT WITH THOSE CHANGES, I DONT HAVE EMAIL ACCESS NOW

Comment: dont save indexpath it will raise issues

Comment: first time it works perfectly but when you delete all the rows and add new ones is when it start to not work

Comment: follow these steps so you can understand what I mean, 1) add multiple rows 2) select all the rows 3) delete all the rows 4) add new rows 5) select all the new rows 6) force quit the app (remove from background) 7) open the app you can see that some of the new rows are deselected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173093/discussion-between-coderj13-and-praveen-gowlikar).

Comment: Hi @CoderJ13 you need to make changes as per your requirement and test well to resolve issues.

Comment: Add  UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: myarray[(indexPath?.row)!]) in editingStyle == .delete

Comment: Add UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: myarray[(indexPath?.row)!]) in editingStyle == .delete

Answer (score 0):

You could use `func prepareForReuse()` method in the UITableViewCell to make sure the checkbox is unselected when you insert a new row.

Comment: hey can you write a code exemple or if you can send me an email with the updated project.

Answer (score 0):

You store in userdefaults the value of the checked button according to its indexpath. The problem with this attitude is when you delete the cell, the new cell is getting the indexpath of the previous cell which is wrong.

You should work with a model to represent your rows. Store in the "ScheduleArray" an object instead of just a string.

Something like that:

```
struct myRow {
    var title: String = ""
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: hey sorry but I don't have enough time to make it. It's not a small refactor.
anyway, what's blocking you from doing that yourself?